# How to pass transaction data parameters(like amount) through a form without <hidden> as this can be changed from the client console

Tags: javascript, php, forms, security

I have a website in which there is a form to enter user details when the user "Proceeds to checkout" after adding items to the cart. The order's item string and the amount are added in the form as -hidden- parameters so that they can go to the next page for php processing and finally getting updated in the database as an ORDER.
Looking from a hacker's perspective, I can easily change the -ORDER/ cart- string as well as the -Amount- value to a less value in my client side "inspect element" and the changed values proceed in the next forms.
What is the tactic to tackle this?

Comment: What about using sessions?

Comment: Why would hacker want to do that?

Comment: That's exactly what I was prepared to ask :))

Comment: Yes you can try session.

Comment: @kingkero Got it! Thanks

Comment: @AlexeyTen: If they can alter hidden fields containing prices then they can order things for free. There was a case once where a hacker changed the prices to negative. So when they ordered they got a refund to their card, as well as getting the goods delivered. Even though the price was on the packing slip, the packer didn't notice the negative and sent it anyway.

Comment: If you have prices in hidden fields instead of a server, you've got serious troubles anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use server-side session. This would store the amount on the server in a value that cannot be changed by the client. When you finalize the order, make sure they paid what they were supposed to. This would use a small amount of memory on the server.

Another option would be to use an HMAC. Calculate the HMAC of the various values in the order, and pass the HMAC through your payment system. Make sure the values in the order give you the same HMAC at the end of the transaction as the HMAC you generated earlier. This would use no memory on the server but require a little extra CPU time.

Comment: Prices are probably better looked up in the db rather than being stored per session or hmac'd on the client.

Comment: @SilverlightFox sure, unless they change during the session